# Delete is slow in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: `old_data` and `new_data`.

Both tables have columns:
 ID, date, value

I want to delete any rows in "old_data" which are not in "new_data", but only between selected dates.

This works in psql:

```
DELETE FROM old_data
WHERE (id, date) NOT IN (SELECT id, date FROM new_data) AND
    id = my_id  AND  date >= 'my_start_date'  AND  date <= 'my_end_date';
```

The start/end dates differ for each id, so I have to run the DELETE separately for each distinct id. There are about 1000 distinct id's in "new_data".

The problem is it is very slow - it takes an hour when "old_data" has 15 million rows and "new_data" has 100,000 rows.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Show the complete tables definitions including all constraints, checks and indexes for both tables.

Comment: Put the `WHERE` constraints into the subquery, and skip selecting `date` since you wont need it. That should help at least partially for a query with this structure.

Comment: @vol7ron: why would it make it slower? Do you take into account that without indexes it's a full scan over 100k x 15M rows (1.5e12 rows)

Comment: @zerkms that was a mistype, it should have read, it will be slower without indexes, or faster with — I'll delete the comment anyhow.  The absence of an index will only make deletions/insertions faster when a `where` clause is not involved.  You've already pointed out that he should list the table definition, which should bring some clarity.  I'm also curious if he has the hardware to support the operations.

Comment: I guess the problem is the "NOT IN" and the sever can't find an optimized plan. Try build a temp table with old_data.id and new_data.id (nid),create an index on matched_old_new (ID), then delete the old_data by joining the old_data and temp table where nid is null.

Comment: please show output of `explain your_query`

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 3):

create these index before running the query .

```
create index old_data_id_index 
on old_data
using btree (id);

create index old_data_date_index
 on old_data
using btree(date);

create index new_data_id_index
 on new_data
 using btree(id);


create index new_data_date_index
 on new_data
using btree(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
delete from old_data removed
using
    (select od.id, od.date
    from old_data od
    left join new_data nd on nd.id=od.id and nd.date=od.date
    where new_data.id is null) as to_remove
where to_remove.id=removed.id and to_remove.date=removed.date and
-- rest of your conditions:
removed.id = my_id  AND  removed.date >= 'my_start_date'  AND  removed.date <= 'my_end_date';
```

This should avoid scanning `new_data` table multiple times;